# Swap disk devices in RHEL 8

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel8, udev

I need to swap a couple of disk devices around on a RHEL 8 server because it's unfortunately going to be problematic to rebuild it and I need the devices in a specific order.

I think the following udev rules used to work in RHEL 6, but then that didn't use systemd:

```
KERNEL=="sdb", NAME="sdb_old"
KERNEL=="sdc", NAME="sdb"
KERNEL=="sdb_old", NAME="sdc"
```

They don't work in RHEL 8.

Looking at the systemd udev documentation, it looks like "NAME" is now only used for network interfaces.

Comment: XY problem. You probably don't need to swap them. Have a look at /dev/disk/ instead.